# Reduce cell width and font size of table using pandoc.table()

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, pandoc, pander

I'm using `knitr` and `pander` to make a table in a markdown file. I'm converting the markdown file to a PDF using Pandoc from within R.

This code:

````
library(knitr)

```{r myTable, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, results='asis', comment=""}

library(pander)
pandoc.table(head(iris))

```
````

then running this function within R:

```
knitsPDF <- function(name) {
  knit(paste0(name, ".Rmd"), encoding = "utf-8")
  callformat <-"pandoc -V geometry:margin=1in  %s.md -o %s.pdf"
  system(sprintf(callformat, name, name))
}

knitsPDF(name) # insert file name of .Rmd file
```

produces this table in the PDF file:

[image]

How can I 1. Reduce width of columns in table? 2. Reduce font size of table?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you do not want to split the table into multiple parts based on its width, you can specify that directly in `split.tables` parameter with `pandoc.table` or more generally in `table.split.table` in `panderOptions`. E.g.:

```
> pandoc.table(head(iris), split.table = Inf)

-------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sepal.Length   Sepal.Width   Petal.Length   Petal.Width   Species 
-------------- ------------- -------------- ------------- ---------
     5.1            3.5           1.4            0.2       setosa  

     4.9             3            1.4            0.2       setosa  

     4.7            3.2           1.3            0.2       setosa  

     4.6            3.1           1.5            0.2       setosa  

      5             3.6           1.4            0.2       setosa  

     5.4            3.9           1.7            0.4       setosa  
-------------------------------------------------------------------

> panderOptions('table.split.table', 300)
> pander(head(iris))

-------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sepal.Length   Sepal.Width   Petal.Length   Petal.Width   Species 
-------------- ------------- -------------- ------------- ---------
     5.1            3.5           1.4            0.2       setosa  

     4.9             3            1.4            0.2       setosa  

     4.7            3.2           1.3            0.2       setosa  

     4.6            3.1           1.5            0.2       setosa  

      5             3.6           1.4            0.2       setosa  

     5.4            3.9           1.7            0.4       setosa  
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

About fontsize: Pandoc's markdown do not have any special syntax for that, so you might use LaTeX markup for your pdf. E.g. just issue a `\footnotesize` directive before your table. See possible font sizes for more details: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts#Sizing_text

Comment: Adding `\normalsize` after the table (one empty line after table caption) makes the font size normal after the table (if using the `\footnotesize` for the table).

Answer (score 1):

You can change the fontsize for specific cells in pander, and thus the entire table, but as a workaround using latex code.

Where your cell is, if the data populating your cell is "770" next to another cell populated by "$731,258", 
If you replace the first cell by `paste0("\\scriptsize", "770")`, your output will look like something like this:

[image]

as you can see, the "770" is in a smaller font.
You can do this with any latex font tag.